# jquery ajax form submit request with first click is not working what is the possible cause

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

> on first click it doesn't get a response but on second click it gives the desired effect
>
> i am using mutiple forms

```html
<form action="" method="" id="formproduct">
  <input
    type="hidden"
    name="id"
    class="productid"
    value="<?php echo   $row['Product_id'];?>"
  />
  <button name="submit" class="btn">Add To Cart</button>
</form>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
      jQuery("#formproduct").submit(function(event){
          event.preventDefault();
          $("form").on("click", "button[name=submit]", function(){
              var form = $(this).closest("form"); // find the form to relate to
              var formData = { product: $(".productid", form).val() };
              jQuery.ajax({
                  type: "POST",
                  url: "server-cart.php",///contain the url of ajax
                  data:formData,
                  dataType:"json",
                  success : function (response){}
             });
          }
      }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Your binding your on click logic inside your on submit handler.  So you have to submit before you can submit ajax.  Move it outside the on submit handler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
jQuery("#formproduct").submit(function(event){
    ...
    $("form").on("click", "button[name=submit]", function(){});
    ...
});
```

That is binding a submit handler.  When the form submits, that logic then binds the click handler to the form.  So then afterwards clicking the form submit button will execute that logic.  If you want the click logic to happen the first time you will have to move it outside that submit handler.

Answer (score 1):

Just get rid of the click handler and do the ajax directly in the submit handler

```
jQuery("#formproduct").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var form = $(this); // "this" is the form
    var formData = {
        product: $(".productid", form).val()
    };
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "server-cart.php", ///contain the url of ajax 
        data: formData,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(response) {}
    });

});
```

The benefit will be user can submit using keyboard also